# Express router, Router.post executing before router.use middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, router

My problem is that for some reason express router doesn't wait for next() function inside middleware and goes str8 to execution fo router.post.

```
Router.use('/posts/add', addPosts);
Router.post('/posts/add', (req, res) => {
    if(req.success){
        res.status(200).send('post added');
    }else{
        res.status(400).send({error: true, message: 'sth went wrong'})
    }
    
});
```

Below is the middleware code:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (req.authorization && req.authorization.access_level < 3) {
            let post = new postsModel(req.body);
            post.save().then(post => {
                console.log(post);
                    req.success = true;
                next();
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error('unauthorized access');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: true, message: err.message });
    }
};
```

Despite middlewares execution, router for some reason is always executing the router.post, doesn't wait for the next() function therefore awlays return error. Anybody could help with that?

Comment: The code shown works as expected.

Comment: For me too. It always execute the mdw and then de post

Comment: If I remove "next()", it should never execute Router.post, but it still does. Dunno what's wrong but it seems like Router is executing both middlewares asynchronously at the same time :/ What should happen above is that req.success shouyld be true when executing Router.post, however it's undefined, because execution comes beforhands or sth:/

Comment: I've added console.logs to track the execution order, it seems that middleware is executed, then the post, however middleware does not wait for the promise execution before goin into router.post, whats surprising for some reason next() is irrelevant inside the middleware as express goes into router.post anyways. Not sure, is there some specific behaviour related to asynchronous code inside middlewares?

Comment: I assume your code contains the statement `const addPosts = require("./path/to/your/middleware");`, right?

Comment: Of course it does :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with the following approach:

```
Router.route('/posts/add', addPosts)
      .post((req, res) => {
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to deeply apologize as I haven't posted the code for 1 more middleware invoked before anything else.

```
    try {
        const path = req.path;
        switch (path) {
            case '/add':
                let data = req.body;
                let error = addPostSchema.validate(data).error;
                console.log(error);
                if (error) {
                    throw new Error(error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log('addPost validated');
                    next()
                }
        }
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('walalala');
        res.status(400).send({ error: true, message: err.message });
    }
};
```

As you can see above, I've had double next() invoked. What I didn't know is that invoking next() does not stop rest of the code in middleware from executing, therefore it was prematurly invoking Router.post. Apologies for the confusion. Hope it will help somebody though having similiar problem.

Comment: I think you can put return before the next `return next()` to stop the rest of the execution.